# How to add view on imageView?

Tags: android

I have created a class that extends a view which will work as a drawing slate to draw a text. I want to add that drawing slate in image View. And I have main activity which contains a scrollable list on top and a image view below list. Now I want to add that View(Drawing slate) on image View. So how to implement this? I tried lot, but I am not getting how to do this.Do i need to use any other view instead of image View? Please help as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create 2 ImageViews, in a FrameLayout, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

just extend ImageView and do your drawing in onDraw method, make sure you call super.onDraw()

Comment: Actually I have created a separate class for drawing that extends a view,let this class as "A". And its working properly for drawing. Now I have another class,Suppose class "B", that contains a horizontal scroll view and Image View. I want to add "A" on Image View in B. Means I want to draw on same activity that contains scroll view. Should I use any other View or layout instead of Image View?

Comment: is your class A always to be used on top of ImageView? if so, then extend ImageView and do your drawing here, if not, use FrameLayout with two children: ImageView and your A class

Comment: I am not getting. I am new to android. I have created a separate class for drawing. Now I have changed image view with frame layout. But now, how to set that drawing class in frame layout. You mean that if use frame layout, then I can draw on it. Right? So what I am saying, I have created class for drawing. So what to do now. Can u please tell me which method is used? Or which operations I should perform to set drawing class code to frame layout? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: if you have FrameLayout just add those two views to that FrameLayout

Comment: No. In XML layout File I have a Relative layout that contains scroll view and image View. Now I replaced Image View with frame layout. So now my main relative layout contains scroll view on top. and in remaining place I have frame layout. So what i want to do, I want to add that separate class in frame layout. How to perform this?

Comment: just add them: <FrameLayout><ImageView/><YourView/></FrameLayout>

Comment: I have alreaady added frame layout in XML. How to add separate class in this frame layout. Frame layout is in another activity. And drawing class is in another activity. How to add this in frame layout using java code?

Comment: add your custom view to xml layout file as i said before, more on this here http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: No you are not getting what I am talking about. I dont want to add it in xml layout file. I want to add class that I have created for drawing in frame layout. Anyways thanks.

Comment: is this FrameLayout defined in xml layout file? if yes, add your view in the same xml file, if not, call frameLayout.addView()